# Unmanaged code callback - method calls counting

Tags: c#, multithreading

My app have a method in C# called by a camera driver unmaged code, it is registered using a delegate. I want to count everytime this method is called.

Sample:

```
bool firtTime;
uint counter;
//firtTime is reseted (set to true) in another method.
private void MyMethod()
{
    if (firtTime)
    {
        counter = 0;
        firtTime = false;
    }

    counter++;
    //Do stuff
}
```

Is my approach ok or may I get wrong values in counter?

Comment: It is an instance method, so it counts the time it is called from the same instance. If you have another instance the counter is different

Comment: why don't you use static variable with Interlocked.Increment

Comment: You can go with static variable, no need of if block, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If this is called from multiple threads at the same time, then this is not ok.  You have several race conditions that can cause trouble.  Consider using System.Thread.Interlocked.Increment to increment counter.

If you need to protect both counter and firtTime, then consider something like this:

```
bool firtTime;
uint counter;
object sync = new object();
//firtTime is reseted (set to true) in another method.
private void MyMethod()
{
    lock (sync) {
        if (firtTime)
        {
            counter = 0;
            firtTime = false;
        }

        counter++;
    }
    //Do stuff
}
```

Be sure to use lock (sync) { } whenever messing with counter and firtTime in your other code

Comment: It is called by the camera driver, I think it should be a single thread, that is why I'm not using lock. But I'm getting some odd result and I'm trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

```
static int counter = 0;
private void MyMethod()
{
    Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
    //Do stuff
}
```

Static variable are associated with type rather than objects;

counter++ is translated into counter = counter + 1, both a read and a write. So needs to be atomic with Interlocked.Increment

For counter

```
var myCounter = counter == 0 ? 0 : (counter - 1);
```